# Improve and cleaning captcha image to character segmentation

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, captcha

I am working with the problem of separating the numbers of a numeric captcha to train a Convolutional Neural Network. To achieve it, I've tried to apply different threshold methods together with erode and dilate to improve the results. Otsu's thresholding gave me the best result until now. In some images, I got a pretty good result, but others are difficult even for humans. Some examples:

**Good result**:

[image]

[image]

**Bad result:**

[image]

[image]

I am wondering if there is any way of improve the results of the images like the second one. I dont have any experiance using CV, and this is my first contact. Here are some other examples of images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also, here is the python code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Read image and resize
img = cv.imread('img.jpg',0)
img = cv.resize(img, (0,0), fx = 3, fy =3)

# Otsu's thresholding after Gaussian filtering
blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
ret3,th3 = cv.threshold(blur,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)


#_, count, h= cv.findContours(th3, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#cv.drawContours(th3, count, -1, (0,255,0),4)

#Erode, dilate and closing
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
th3 = cv.erode(th3, kernel, iterations=1)
th3 = cv.dilate(th3, kernel, iterations=1)
th3 = cv.morphologyEx(th3, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)

plt.imshow(255-th3, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I think images that are similar to the bad result are nearly impossible to work on. 6222 image can be still possible to extract something from, but the other 2 are very very hard.

Comment: Were those images originally encoded in JPEG? The lossy compression would definitely make things harder, since it introduces additional artifacts.

Comment: @DanMašek yes, they are originally encoded in JPEG

Comment: @Link thanks for your answer. I think you are right. The worst result I got was 8166 in the example above. Even the green and the orange one are not bad as that one. I will try segment the characters and see what an CNN can do trying to decifrate the captcha